# Trying to customize Session class in sqlalchemy

Tags: session, sqlalchemy, customization

I want to execute some code every time my code is doing something with the data base, queries or things like that.

I tried to customize the session class in sqlalchemy with the code bellow:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

class CustomSession(Session):
    def execute(self, *args):
        some code
        super().execute(*args)

db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={'class_': CustomSession})
```

But I get the error:

```
app/__init__.py:6: in <module>
    from app.database import init_db
app/database.py:27: in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={'class_': CustomSession})
../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-project-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:753: in __init__
    self.session = self.create_scoped_session(session_options)
../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-project-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:789: in create_scoped_session
    self.create_session(options), scopefunc=scopefunc
../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-project-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:806: in create_session
    return orm.sessionmaker(class_=SignallingSession, db=self, **options)
E   TypeError: sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker() got multiple values for keyword argument 'class_'
```

I'm following the indications in [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/customizing/#session-class). I changed the imports because using as it is in the doc was causing me `ModuleNotFoundError`

Doing something similar to this, I was able to customize the class Query using the argument "query_cls", so I can customize the classes, whats wrong with what Im doing with the session class?

Comment: What version of flask sqlalchemy are you using?  It seems that maybe you are using 2.* and the docs are for 3.*.

Comment: @IanWilson yeah, I'm using 2.5.1 :( , do you know if is there something similar for this version?

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy?  There might be a way to just use an event listener.